# Fix layers of a slab

Tags: vasp, surfaces, atomic-simulation-environment

How do you fix the bottom layers of a slab to mimic a bulk material in ASE? Any functional that takes the slab object and writes a POSCAR with selective dynamics will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In order to have a bulk, you cannot have a slab. Your cell need to fill the whole space by translation in 3D.

Comment: @Camps for the slab model we fix the bottom layers to mimic the bulk while relaxing the top layers. I am asking if there is a function that takes into account selective dynamics

Comment: So, you are trying to mimic a surface, right?

Comment: @Camps yep by freezing the bottom layers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ase.geometry.get_layers`](https://databases.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/geometry.html#ase.geometry.get_layers) to get the bottom layer indices, and then use [`ase.constraints.FixAtoms`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html#ase.constraints.FixAtoms) to fix these atoms. As I said, with ASE you can imagine atomic structures as Numpy arrays, and then you realize you can do literally whatever you want.

To use a Ni(111) surface as a simple example:

```
from ase.build import fcc111
from ase.geometry import get_layers
from ase.constraints import FixAtoms
from ase.visualize import view
import numpy as np

atoms = fcc111('Ni', (4,4,4), vacuum=5.)
layers = get_layers(atoms, (0, 0, 1), tolerance=0.3)[0]
bot_indices = np.argwhere(layers==0).flatten()
c = FixAtoms(indices=bot_indices)
atoms.set_constraint(c)
view(atoms)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. You have been of immense help solving problems I bring. Thanks once again.

Comment: how do I select the last two bottom layers in your example? When I make changes it only fixes one layer instead of two or three

Comment: Just do `bot_indices = np.argwhere(layers<2).flatten()` for bottom 2 layers for example